# how to make border red if date is invalid in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a form in in which I have two field `DOB` , and `marriage` date .I want if marriage date is `less than DOB` I want to show `red` border .I am able to get if `DOB is greater than marriage` But I am not able to show red border as well I want **form** should be **invalid** if my fields are invalid then my form is also invalid

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/neixp9ZARRAQ33gKSV9u?p=preview

```
 $scope.changedate =function(obj){

    console.log(obj.name)
    if(obj && obj.name){
            obj.longDate = moment(obj.name).format('x');
        }

        if(parseInt($scope.c['marriage date'].longDate) > parseInt($scope.c['date of birth'].longDate)){
          alert('not bigger')
        }
  }




app.directive('viewValueChanged', function viewValueChangedDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                scope.$parent.$eval(attrs['viewValueChanged']);
            }
            // in case of user entered invalid value
            if(newValue === null) {
                scope.$parent.$eval(attrs['viewValueChanged']);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**if marriage date is bigger  than I want to show red border as well .my form should be invalid**

```
 <form name="userForm">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, x) in c">
       <p class="input-group"  ng-if="x.date=='date'">{{key}}
          <input name="{{key}}" type="text" view-value-changed='changedate(x)' class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="x.name" is-open="x.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="formats" />
                <span id="" ng-if="userForm[key].$invalid" class="help-block" style="margin-bottom:0">Invalid date </span>

          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1(x)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>

         <p class="input-group"  ng-if="x.date=='date2'">{{key}}
          <input  name="{{key}}"type="text" view-value-changed='changedate(x)' class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="x.name" is-open="x.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions2" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="formats" />
            <span id="" ng-if="userForm[key].$invalid" class="help-block" style="margin-bottom:0">Invalid date </span>

          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1(x)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>

        </p>
    </li>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `ng-class`

Something like:

```
 ng-class="{'verified': userForm[key].$invalid}"
```

You can add it to your input.

Then add `.verified` to your css:

```
input.form-control.verified {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWZb5mWN7Qd3eAeA4hsY)

Comment: where is your. logic

Comment: I wrote you: 
1. add the ng-class above to your input.
2. add the style to css.

Comment: Did you click on 'Run' at the top of the plnkr?

Comment: have you implemented your logic in plunker ??

Comment: `help-block` (bootstrap class)already gives you red color .don't use external css

Comment: @AlonShmieli plunker is running ..but your code is not there

Comment: can you please add your logic in your plunker

Comment: Please try again (Updated my response with a new link). I don't know what both of you didn't succeed to use it (It works on incognito).

Open the plnkr, add 'f' to the first date input and then you see a red border.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very simple to apply based on the validity on input field. Add CSS rule and it will trigger when field becomes invalid.

```
inupt[uib-datepicker-popup].ng-invalid {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```